# Unable to install MongoDB extension in PHP 7.1

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, rockmongo

I am trying to install a Mongo DB designer tool *Rock Mongo* which requires PHP.

I tried installing the `mongodb.dll` in `php.ini` by downloading the driver from [Windows.php.net downloads](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/1.1.1/), specifically the file: `php_mongodb-1.1.1-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip`.

Environment

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Apache 2.4 web server
- PHP 7.1
- MongoDB 3.4

Attempt

1. Unzipped and copied `mongodb.dll` to my `php7\ext` directory.
2. I am still getting the following error when I try to open the `ROCKMONGO index.php`.

Comment: "the error" What's the error? Are you seeing a *PHP Starup* error? Or is that an error from Rock Mongo telling you MongoDB isn't installed?

Comment: Changed order for readability with section breakdown and list items and removed unneeded salutation.